# Function returns wrong data if fed a list of numbers as opposed to a single number

Tags: matlab, function, if-statement, plot

I am having a bit of trouble with getting correct output from my function when I plot it.

I have written a simple function that takes `x` as input and just returns `x` as output. But if `x` is greater than `75` I return `25` as an output instead (essentially capping the output to 25 if `x` exceeds 75).

The function works as intended when I feed it a normal number, but when I give it a list of numbers it completely ignores my if-statement and returns just `x` regardless of what the input is.

Full code:

```
x = 0:0.1:200;
y = f(x);
plot(x,y)
function output = f(x)
    if (x >= 75)
        output = 25;
    else
        output = x;
    end
end
```

My plot ends up looking like this:
[image]
But I am I expecting for my plot to look something like this:
[image]

However if I just use the function with a single number it works as intended. For example if I did something like this instead:

```
x = 75;
y = f(x)
function output = f(x)
    if (x >= 75)
        output = 25;
    else
        output = x;
    end
end
```

Why does my function not work with an array input? How do I fix it?

Comment: Not in Suever's answer: `if` with an array only triggers if all elements in the array are true. So if any element in `x` is not `>=75`, then the `else` statement is executed. `if x>=75` is equivalent to `if all(x>=75)`.

Comment: Also, the one liner `output = (x>75).*25 + (x<=75).*x;` works. Logical arrays `(x>75)` and `(x<=75)` are used as masks to select whether 25 or the value from x is chosen. It benefits from Matlab performance on vectorized operations (or rather, does not suffer from Matlab's lack of performance when running for loops). Make it a function handle with the syntax: `output_fcn = @(x) (x>75).*25 + (x<=75).*x; plot(x,output_fcn(x));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want your function to operate on arrays, you need to explicitly change it to work with arrays, or call your function for each element.

## Calling for each element

```
x = [1, 2, 100];

% Calls the function f for each element in x
output = arrayfun(@f, x);
% [1, 2, 25]
```

## Writing `f` to handle arrays

To do this, you can use [logical indexing](https://www.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/matrix-indexing-in-matlab.html) to replace elements in the array where the value is greater than or equal to 75 with 25. *This is going to be the most performant option*

```
function x = f(x)
    % Creates a logical index using `x >= 75` and assigns the value `25`
    % to those elements matching that criteria
    x(x >= 75) = 25;
end

x = [1, 2, 100];
f(x)
% [1, 2, 25]
```

Or you could write your function to loop through the input array

```
function output = f(x)
    output = x
    for k = 1:numel(x)
        if output(k) >= 75
            output(k) = 25
        end
    end
end
```